# UISegmentedControl change number of segments programmatically

Tags: ios, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

Is there a way to change the number of segments programmatically?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Yes, you can use

```
removeSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger) animated:(BOOL)
```

And

```
insertSegmentWithTitle:(NSString *) atIndex:(NSUInteger) animated:(BOOL)
```

Comment: I solved with:    
    [self.SegmentAnswer insertSegmentWithTitle:@"5" atIndex:4 animated:YES];
    [self.SegmentAnswer insertSegmentWithTitle:@"6" atIndex:5

Answer (score 50):

To replace the segments entirely, you can use the following function:

```
- (void)setSegments:(NSArray *)segments
{
    [segmentController removeAllSegments];

    for (NSString *segment in segments) {
        [segmentController insertSegmentWithTitle:segment atIndex:segmentController.numberOfSegments animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was perfect to put into a UISegmentedControl category. Thanks!

Comment: You can use [segmentController removeAllSegments] instead of the while loop. See the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/removeAllSegments

Comment: To double check, it's available for both 7.X and 8.X yeh?

Comment: Edited to use `[segmentController removeAllSegments] ` as per @MCR's comment.

Answer (score 38):

And here's a little Swift extension to replace current segmentedControl with array of new values

#### Swift 3

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func replaceSegments(segments: Array<String>) {
        self.removeAllSegments()
        for segment in segments {
            self.insertSegmentWithTitle(segment, atIndex: self.numberOfSegments, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Swift 4

```
extension UISegmentedControl {
    func replaceSegments(segments: Array<String>) {
        self.removeAllSegments()
        for segment in segments {
            self.insertSegment(withTitle: segment, at: self.numberOfSegments, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a Swift extension for replacing the segments with a sequence of strings. It’s similar to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34070197/7828620) given here except it can be used with any sequence, meaning you can also pass in slices, sets, etc.

```
extension UISegmentedControl {

    /// Replace the current segments with new ones using a given sequence of string.
    /// - parameter withTitles:     The titles for the new segments.
    public func replaceSegments<T: Sequence>(withTitles: T) where T.Iterator.Element == String {
        removeAllSegments()
        for title in withTitles {
            insertSegment(withTitle: title, at: numberOfSegments, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the other answer that you're referring to? You can get a permalink to an answer by clicking on the "share" link under it.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness (and because I ended up here looking for how to achieve the same thing in xib) here is how to do it in xib:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simple than u think : Swift 5.7

```
func setSegmentedControl() {
        // [1] remove all segments
        segmentedControl.removeAllSegments()

        // [2] insert your segments by your model
        ["title1", "title2", "title3"].enumerated().forEach { index, title in
            segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: title, at: index, animated: false)
        }
    
        // [3] optional - select default segment
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

work for me, UIsegmentedControll contains two segments, i want add one in index 2, use this code in swift 2.2 use:

```
SEG_TipoFiltro.insertSegmentWithTitle("Title", atIndex: 2, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

**adding and deleting segments in swift4 using code**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var segment1: UISegmentedControl!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  @IBAction func insert(_ sender: Any) {  
    segment1.insertSegment(withTitle: "\(segment1.numberOfSegments+1)", at: segment1.numberOfSegments, animated: true)  
  }

  @IBAction func remove(_ sender: Any) {  
    segment1.removeSegment(at: segment1.numberOfSegments-1, animated: true)
  }
}
```