# Change number of segments according the arraycount?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, uisegmentedcontrol

I have seen many Questions and still i didn't get exact response I need. Is it possible to change the number of segments in UISegmented control based on array count. When I tried it is showing error:"assigning to readonly property".

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23179457/7084910

Comment: You need to remove all items from UISegmentedControl and insert by array elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try that:

```
- (void)setSegments:(NSArray *)segments {
    [segmentController removeAllSegments];

    for (NSString *segment in segments) {
        [segmentController insertSegmentWithTitle:segment atIndex:segmentController.numberOfSegments animated:NO];
    }
}
```